# Check to see if a div ID matches another elements ID

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fire a function if a div ID matches the ID of another element.

Here is my code:

```
$('.liner-select').each(function() {
if ( $(this).attr('id') == $('#envelope_liner').attr('id') ) {
$(this).addClass('selected');
} else {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
}

});
```

But it doesn't seem to be firing.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well this question in general is bad because ID's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Functions don't "fire." Events fire. Is there some event listener which should call this code? [Please provide a **complete** example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also, element IDs must be unique.

Comment: Each '.liner-select' has a different ID in sequence. 1,2,3,4.  So each ID is unique.

Comment: @user1226560 those ID's may be unique, but if you're still checking to see if they are equivalent to ANOTHER element, you should rethink your solution.

Comment: As there must be only one ID in a page, so why don't you use the following ?

$('#envelope_liner').addClass('selected');

Comment: @RUJordan OK - i see what you're saying.  I've changed the attribute on the second element to 'liner-id' and it still doesn't work.  My element is <div class="liner-check" liner-id="1"></div>

Comment: can you share the relevant html

Comment: Can you please share the complete code ?

Comment: From what I can see it should be simplified as `$('.liner-select').removeClass('selected');
var id = $('#envelope_liner').attr('liner-id');
$('#' + id + '.liner-select').addClass('selected');`

Comment: @ArunPJohny that selector is overspecified. `$('#' + id)` will match at most 1 element so there's no reason to add the class selector on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.

@RUJordan you were correct.  I was stupidly using 2 ID's which were the same.  Using another attribute worked fine.  Final Code:

```
$('.liner-select').each(function() {
if ( $(this).attr('id') == $('#envelope_liner').attr('liner-id') ) {
$(this).addClass('selected');
} else {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
}

});
```

Thanks